# MYSQL Use avg + group by + distinct

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make an avarage of a value but data are duplicated and I'm using group by for other thing. Let's see :

Table AA :

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
-------------------
A    |  3   |  001
A    |  6   |  002
```

Table BB :

```
Col1 | Col2
-----------
001  |  10
001  |  20
002  |  30
```

I join table AA with table BB with AA.Col3=BB.Col1

I group result with AA.Col1

I sum all data of BB.Col2

I need the average of AA.Col2

My final result would be :

```
AA.Col1 | avg(AA.Col2) | sum(BB.Col2)
-------------------------------------
A | 4.5 | 60
```

sql :

```
select AA.col1,avg(AA.Col2),sum(BB.Col2) 
from AA join BB on AA.Col3=BB.Col1 
group by AA.Col1,AA.Col3
```

That's not working 
Is it possible to have only one group by for AA.Col1 and a distinct AA.Col3 for the avg of AA.Col2?

Thanks Tom for editing this.

Other precision,

```
select * from 
(select AA.col1,avg(AA.Col2),sum(BB.Col2) 
from AA join BB on AA.Col3=BB.Col1 
group by AA.Col3) CC
group by CC.Col1
```

is not my option, I want to find an other way